# Jenkins plugins failed to install properly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

I'm installing Jenkins first time and some to the suggested plugins are not installing.

Error: 
Installation Failures
Some plugins failed to install properly, you may retry installing them or continue.

Is there any way to install it.[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUtDd.png)

Comment: Are you using container or proxy (Docker, Nginx)?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some network connectivity issue to download plugin. Or else, you can download jenkins plugin hpi file and manually installed them.